Call IterateOverInstancesOfClass getting stuck
I'm trying to call JVMTI->IterateOverInstancesOfClass from JNI (like here) but the call is getting stuck.
I aim to find an instance of a specific class to call a non-static method.
I saw this sentence in the documentation:

As a result, threads executing Java programming language code, threads attempting to resume the execution of Java programming language code, and threads attempting to execute JNI functions are typically stalled.

Regarding this sentence, I ran it in a native thread that I created in the JVM process. I think it might have some effect (maybe my thread is stalled either because it's not a normal JVM thread).
Does anyone have any idea why it could happen? How to solve it? Are you familiar with a different method for calling a method on a specific instance of a class?
Conceptually this is my code:
// Get JVM
int vmCount;
JavaVM* jvm_array[1];
JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(jvm_array, 1, &vmCount);
JavaVM* jvm = jvm_array[0];

// AttachThread
JNIEnv* env;
JavaVMAttachArgs args;
args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
args.name = "main";
args.group = NULL;
(*jvm)->AttachCurrentThread(jvm, (void**) &env, &args);

// Get JVMTI
jvmtiEnv* jvmti;
(*jvm)->GetEnv(jvm, (void**) &jvmti, JNI_VERSION_1_2);

// Enable can tag objects
jvmtiCapabilities cap = {0};
cap.can_tag_objects = 1;
(*jvmti)->AddCapabilities(jvmti, &cap);

// Find class using jvmti->GetLoadedClasses
jclass class = ...;

// Iterate over instances in heap
(*jvmti)->IterateOverInstancesOfClass(jvmti, class, JVMTI_HEAP_OBJECT_EITHER, callback, NULL);

...

static jvmtiIterationControl JNICALL
HeapObjectCallback(jlong class_tag, jlong size, jlong* tag_ptr, void* user_data) {
    *tag_ptr = 1;
    return JVMTI_ITERATION_CONTINUE;
}

I tried to attach the thread as daemon and to deattach the thread before calling IterateOverInstancesOfClass. Nothing worked :(

Show the full code. What does callback look like?
